# Using O-Profile with Linux RedHat OS => conflict with NMI watchdog

Tags: linux, redhat, oprofile

I was trying to run o-profile (a profiling program for linux) and kept getting an error while starting saying something like counter 0 was being use by 'NMI watchdog'. Is NMI part of the OS or is it a separate package that was downloaded?  How would I go about uninstalling it?

I tried this on another Linux machine with the same OS and specs and O-Profile ran with no errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NMI (Non maskable interrupt) watchdog is a hardware watchdog timer that detects if software has crashed in order to force an automatic hardware reset of the system.

Comment: ok so I assume NMI is using some of the counters needed by O-Profile since O-Profile uses processor counters to gather statistics.  Would that be correct?  Is NMI part of RedHat or is it a separate package and can be uninstalled?

Comment: This link explains it and says how to disable it.  http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxinfo/v3r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fliaai%2Fcrashdump%2Fliaaicrashdumpnmiwatch.htm

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem on a RHEL6 bsaed distribution. When doing

```
sudo opcontrol --start
```

I got:

```
Error: counter 0 not available nmi_watchdog using this resource ? Try:
opcontrol --deinit
echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/nmi_watchdog
```

Executing the last two lines of this message (de-initializing oprofile and stopping the NMI watchdog) solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

running `echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/nmi_watchdog` after `opcontrol --deinit` and before `opcontrol --start` should work. Essentially what you are doing by running that command is disabling the nmi_watchdog.